# How can I access WCF server using xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, walkthrough

I just followed "Walkthrough - Working with WCF". But I can't get any data from server.

I did make Proxy and add it to Android project [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQkau.png)

**Here is my Activity**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using HelloWorldServiceProxy;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using static Java.Util.Jar.Attributes;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    [Activity(Label = "HelloWorld", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        static readonly EndpointAddress Endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWorldService/?wsdl");

        HelloWorldServiceClient _client;
        Button _getHelloWorldDataButton;
        TextView _getHelloWorldDataTextView;
        Button _sayHelloWorldButton;
        TextView _sayHelloWorldTextView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            InitializeHelloWorldServiceClient();

            // This button will invoke the GetHelloWorldData - the method that takes a C# object as a parameter.
            _getHelloWorldDataButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.getHelloWorldDataButton);
            _getHelloWorldDataButton.Click += GetHelloWorldDataButtonOnClick;
            _getHelloWorldDataTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.getHelloWorldDataTextView);

            // This button will invoke SayHelloWorld - this method takes a simple string as a parameter.
            _sayHelloWorldButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.sayHelloWorldButton);
            _sayHelloWorldButton.Click += SayHelloWorldButtonOnClick;
            _sayHelloWorldTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.sayHelloWorldTextView);
        }
        void InitializeHelloWorldServiceClient()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttpBinding();
            _client = new HelloWorldServiceClient(binding, Endpoint);
        }

        static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttpBinding()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            };

            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            return binding;
        }
        async void GetHelloWorldDataButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = new HelloWorldData
            {
                Name = "Mr. Chad",
                SayHello = true
            };

            _getHelloWorldDataTextView.Text = "Waiting for WCF...";
            HelloWorldData result;
            try
            {
                result = await _client.GetHelloDataAsync(data);
                _getHelloWorldDataTextView.Text = result.Name;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        async void SayHelloWorldButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _sayHelloWorldTextView.Text = "Waiting for WCF...";
            try
            {
                var result = await _client.SayHelloToAsync("Kilroy");
                _sayHelloWorldTextView.Text = result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to get data from Server...? What Did I do wrong...? Or Is there any wrong in Walkthrough?

Comment: "I can't get any data from server." - What does it mean? Did you get an exception? What is retuned from await _client.SayHelloToAsync("Kilroy")?

Comment: are you testing this on the emulator or device?

Comment: @EvZ Yes! I got Exception! System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: System error./System.EventArgs
I've also tried replace Local Ip addres instead of "localhost:8733" but it doesn't working..

Comment: @MichaelRandall I tested on the emulator..!

Answer (score 2):

There several issues with testing WCF on Xamarin and Andriod

- If you are on the *Emulator*, *LocalHost* will not work
- If you are on either the *Emulator* or *Device*, *IISExpress* will not allow a connection

There are many remedies for this, however the easiest way i found to test this, is the following (not i don not recommend leaving your firewall off)

- Turn your firewall off
- Find your WCF applicationhost.config file ie at (.vs\config)

  - or right click `issexpress -> show all applications`, click the service, and go to the config path
  - Find your service and edit the bindings similar to the below for your site.

**Example changes**

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:43420:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:43420:127.0.0.1" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:43420:<put your IP address here>" />
```

> **Note** : You will have to change `43420` to your *WCF* Service *Ip
>   Address* and change `<put your IP address here>` to your local PC *IP Address*

*For a more permanent solution you will need to look up how to configure your *Advanced Firewall Settings.*

Furthermore, accessing `LocalHost` on your emulator wont work. On the *Emulator Virtual machine* , the *LocalHost* refers to the device on which the code is running (the emulator).

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the *Android Emulator*, use the *IP address* `10.0.2.2` instead. You can read more from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

Comment: I turned my firewall off and tried it but it still not working.. and I didn't use IIS Express......

Comment: You will still have to use 10.0.2.2 instead of local host in the emulator

Comment: This worked for me. I can now access my WCF service through the Android emulator at http://10.0.2.2:55724/MyService.svc